Interest in High-Precision Linux Packet Replay Tool Using SO_TXTIME?
I’ve recently completed a thesis on developing a Linux-based Ethernet packet replay program that achieves high precision using the SO_TXTIME kernel option. This program is designed to replicate network packets, especially UDP packets, with accuracy in the low microseconds to nanoseconds range. Its primary goal is to enable precise replay and analysis of various network errors.
Before I publish my work, I’d like to gauge if there’s interest in such a tool. The code is functional and in good shape, but I still need to refactor it a bit. If this topic intrigues you or if you have any specific questions or feedback, please let me know!
Thanks in advance!

Hi! I'm afraid this isn't a technical question, but asking for feedback and opinion; as per our rules (see the help pages, "what questions should I avoid asking"), these are the things you should not ask on here! But: you should clearly speak to the communities of projects that already do similar things; there's more than one, but from the top of my head, there's tc and various traffic simulator frameworks. I do have doubts about your accuracy claims without heavy hardware support – nanosecond determinism ranges are technically impossible in Ethernet. You simply can't choose when the

network is ready for you ethernet frame. And, software sending the command to the NIC to send a packet now has jitter, as well. But it might work with specialized NICs! So, do talk to the existing frameworks, and get your feedback there. Put your code up – no matter how untidy it is – people will want to discuss architecture, not style of punctuation. (Do note that running an automated code formatter over your code base should still be done, but I'm certain that's been part of your development workflow, anyways)
